# Optimum way of working with excel data in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, oop, automation, nunit

I have built a custom data-driven framework in selenium with C# and NUnit. I'm using excel sheets (.xlsx) to store my test data and read from it. However, some excel sheets have loads of columns and when using the test case source attribute
`[TestCaseSource(nameof(methodWhichExtractsData), new object[] { "ExcelFileName" })]`, the number of parameters in my test methods are getting out of hand. Some excel sheets have over 50 columns (some forms in the application I'm testing have a lot of fields). What is the best / industry standard way of reading from the excel sheet in such situations?.

I was thinking of using DTOs to represent the test data but I'm not sure if that's the correct way. I haven't had much success trying to find a solution online either.

Comment: From what I understand your problem is more related to the architecture of your classes/methods rather than from Data Source perspective. If you have many arguments in a method, try to use something like builder pattern instead of using methods with many params. Data source might remain the same. Instead of passing 15 params you better pass one object instance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.